# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Spring-data-Jpa

Tags: spring-data

I am getting an exception

```
<code>
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditTrailRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.<init>(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:39)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 35 more

</code>
```

My repository is defined as

```
<code>
public interface AuditTrailRepository extends CrudRepository<AuditTrail, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<AuditTrail> {


    public List<AuditTrail> findByKey(String key);

     @Query("select u from AuditTrail u where u.createdDate between :startDate and :endDate ")
     List<AuditTrail> findByDateRange(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);

     @Query("select u from AuditTrail u where u.createdDate between :startDate and :endDate and key = :clientId ")
     List<AuditTrail> findByDateRangeForClient(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, 
             @Param("endDate") Date endDate,
             @Param("ClientId") String clientId);


}
</code>
```

My entity is

```
<code>
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUDIT_TRAIL")
public class AuditTrail extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1647646453787027659L;
    private Long id;
    // ClientID from  
    private String key;
    private TaskType taskType;
    // Inbound / Outbound
    private FileActionType action;
    private String userName;
    private String message;
    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;

</code>
```

The persistance.xml in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF is

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="spring-jpa" />

</persistence>
</code>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Answering my own question here .......**

The only thing that worked for me listing each domain entity in persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="spring-jpa" >
        <class>com.multiplan.edi.common.domain.AuditTrail</class>

   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you see the exception posted is that we swallow an exception thrown by the `EntityManager` trying to lookup an `EntityType` from the `Metamodel`. I've created [a JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-93) to keep track of that.

Generally speaking, the need to list classes explicitly depends on the setup of your JPA persistence provider. Some of them can be configured to scan a package for entities. Others require to list at least root classes.

Comment: What kind of activity do you expect? It's been resolved in early September 20*11* and already released over a year ago…

Comment: sorry . I just check out. thanks btw .. can you help me one thing, Im getting kind of crazy about an exception :https://gist.github.com/4143358 can you please help on this?