# Spring Data JPA Repository: IllegalArgumentException this argument is required

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, maven, repository

I am trying to configure repositories using Spring Data JPA.  I get the following exception when trying to execute my tests.  I can get it to work and then I compile using Maven and my tests fail.  Then I go back to manually run the tests, and they fail (All without changing any code).  I am guessing that it might be a path problem, but I've started with a clean project and continue to have issues.  My exception is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.vinoetic.vinoeticLibrary.util.ContextHelper.getContext(ContextHelper.java:15)
    at com.vinoetic.vinoeticLibrary.repository.TestPersonRepository.testRepository(TestPersonRepository.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.<init>(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:131)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:38)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 29 more
[/code]
```

My pom includes the following dependencies (among others)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
</dependency> 


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-data-commons-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

My entity is:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

My entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@Data public class Person {

    @Id
    private Long personId = null;
    private Long userId = null;
    private String lastName = null;
    private String firstName = null;
    private String email = null;
    private String phoneHome = null;
    private String phoneCell = null;
    private String phoneWork = null;
    private Date birthdate = null;
    private String namePrefix = null;
    private String title = null;
    @Column(columnDefinition="tinyint")
    private Boolean sendNewsletter = false;
    private String facebookURL = null;
    private String profileImageURL = null;

    @Transient
    private UserProfileImage profileImages = null;


}
```

My context setup is:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="vinoeticDataSource_MySQL" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="vinoeticDataSource_MySQL" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<!-- JPA -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.vinoetic.interfacesAndModels.repositories.sql"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="emf1" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

<bean id="emf1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="vinoeticDataSource_MySQL" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

And finally, my persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                version="2.0" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've spent 3 days on this and I can't seem to get this to work consistently.  As I mentioned, I can get it to work, but if I compile using maven, my tests fail.  Then rerunning my tests in Eclipse, they fail with the above exception.

I've looked at other posts here and tried the suggestions.  I referred to:

[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Spring-data-Jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931331/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-in-spring-data-jpa)

I tried what they recommend, but then I get an error that there isn't a persistence provider.  I can't seem to get anything to work consistently.

Using:

STS 2.8.0.RELEASE
JDK 1.6

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of Spring-data-jpa are you using?

Comment: The issue you refer the suggest solution asks you to list all the entity classes in persistence.xml - not to add the provider as you have done above.

Comment: Another thing to try would be to test with straight JPA - inject EntityManager into a junit test and see if you can query the entity using it.  This is most probably an issue due to a wrong JPA configuration which is showing up as spring-data error.

Answer (score 2):

I have stumbled across this question as I had the same problem.

I found that I was able to use `JPA` Repositories in my Unit Tests if I:

1. Created a seperate `ApplicationContext` for testing purposes which supplied the Repository.
2. Introduced the `ApplicationContext` for use with the text using the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation.
3. Creating a class property for the Repository, then annotating the setter method with `@Inject`

I found "[JUnit and Spring - What You Don't Know](https://dzone.com/articles/junit-spring-%E2%80%93-what-you-don%E2%80%99t)" to be invaluable.

I hope this helps someone - I know this is a very old thread but Google + StackOverFlow = happy smiley faces probably sometime in 2015!